# Can Cypress be used with browserstack to connect to real devices using browserstack to test web application

Tags: android, ios, cypress, browserstack

My intention is to use Cypress with browserstack to connect to real devices to test web application. I want to run the Cypress tests on iOS and Android devices.

Is it possible to do so? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

BrowserStack list supported for running test on cypress https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/cypress/browsers-and-os

Cypress itself does not support running tests on real devices but you can set Browser dimensions: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/07/08/end-to-end-testing-mobile-apps-with-ionic-and-cypress/